# Apache Camel Cannot modify json response

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-camel, cxfrs

I'm bothered with returning an updated JSON, in fact, I receive a JSON defined as an opportunity (it's a business term, we don't need to explain it) from the cxfrs endpoint, convert it to String, then check the method invoked in jax-rs controller, if the we want make an update of Affair json, we publish the message as string in queue **q.gestioncougar.cl.creation** as described below:

```xml
<route id="serviceToCustomerLinksInboundRouting">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:oab_serviceToObsIT?loggingFeatureEnabled={{gestioncougar.wscall.log.enable}}&amp;loggingSizeLimit={{gestioncougar.wscall.log.size}}" />
        <to uri="bean:log?method=info(*,'Body : ${body}')"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />            
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.operationName} == 'updateAffair'</simple>
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:q.gestioncougar.cl.creation?disableReplyTo=true" />
            </when>
        </choice>
</route>
```

The config of cxfrs service that is bonded to jax-rs controller:

```xml
<cxf:rsServer address="{{gestioncougar.service.in.obsit.url}}" id="oab_serviceToObsIT"
    serviceClass="fr.oab.sie.esb.gestioncougar.customerLink.controller.CougarToCL" />
```

The JAX-RS controller:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CougarToCL {

    @PUT
    @Path("/updateAffair")
    void updateAffair(String request);

}
```

Then we create a route that read from the queue **q.gestioncougar.cl.creation**, next unmarshal the body to POJO format (Java Model), moreover, read it by the method **convertToCLFormat** defined in the bean **traiterCallFromCougar**:

```xml
<route id="serviceToCustomerLinksCreationOutboundRoute">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:q.gestioncougar.cl.creation" />
        <!-- Sauvegarde du body initial -->
        <unmarshal ref="formatJsonOpportunity" />
        <!-- Sauvegarde du body -->
        <setProperty propertyName="savedBody">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <bean ref="traiterCallFromCougar" method="convertToCLFormat"/>
        <to uri="bean:log?method=info(*,'CustomerLinks Body Format: ${body}')"/>
</route>
```

The method **convertToCLFormat**:

```
public void convertToCLFormat(Exchange exchange){
    Opportunity opportunity = exchange.getProperty("savedBody",Opportunity.class);
    EsbLogger.info(exchange, "opportunity {}", opportunity.toString());
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 200);
    Affair affair = opportunityAffairMapper.toDealCL(opportunity.getDealCL());
    String clBody = affairJsonParser.parsePojoToJson(affair);
    EsbLogger.info(exchange, "affair {}", clBody);
    exchange.getOut().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
    exchange.getOut().setBody(clBody);
}
```

and here is the problem !, even if I set the body with the newly mapped JSON defined as Affair, I don't see any change in postman response, but the body is changed when I check the log.

Take a look at the postman request:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the converted JSON into the "out" message, but rather in the "in" one.

This was so confusing that they now recommend to simply use `exchange.getMessage()` (without any distinction whether *in* or *out*)

See more here:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_getout_on_exchange

So this should work:

```
exchange.getMessage().setBody(clBody);
```

Comment: I changed to exchange.getIn().setBody(body), but the body isn't updated !